# How to upgrade Entity framework to get system.data.EntityClient.dl?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ado.net, entity-framework-4.1

I am New to Entity Framework.I am in supporting of the project created in Visual studion2010 , MVC 3 and Entity Framework.
in my PC ,i am having VS 2010,Mvc and entityframwork ,when i build that project in my PC .
it build successfully.but giving the error 
"The specified store provider cannot be found in the configuration, or is not valid."
they have used providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" in connection string.
How to resolve this problem...?

i checked
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entityclient.entityconnection.aspx
and
installed some tools but it didnt help...

Comment: That provider is part of Entity Framework itself which is part of .NET framework.

Comment: Make sure you referenced System.Data.Entity.dll (it's is part of .NET Framework) in addition to EntityFramework.dll

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the configuration section to your web.config, most probably it's the "cannot be found in the configuration" part of the error message that is causing this. Add the following to your web.config, just after the  section:

```
<system.data>
        <DbProviderFactories>
            <add name="EF Caching Data Provider" invariant="EFCachingProvider" description="Caching Provider Wrapper" type="EFCachingProvider.EFCachingProviderFactory, EFCachingProvider, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=def642f226e0e59b"/>
            <add name="EF Caching Data Provider for Web" invariant="EFCachingProvider.Web" description="Caching Provider Wrapper for Web" type="EFCachingProvider.Web.EFCachingProviderFactory, EFCachingProvider.Web, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=def642f226e0e59b"/>
            <add name="EF Generic Provider Wrapper" invariant="EFProviderWrapper" description="Generic Provider Wrapper" type="EFProviderWrapperToolkit.EFProviderWrapperFactory, EFProviderWrapperToolkit, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=def642f226e0e59b"/>
        </DbProviderFactories>
    </system.data>
```